# Error creating StandardAppVersion: googleapi: Error 404: App does not exist

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hi i am trying to create a simple node app on google app standard app engine using this terraform code. This code used to work before but today i was trying to restart the whole project and re-deploy everything again and i see that i am getting an error.

**compute_engine.tf**

```
resource "google_app_engine_standard_app_version" "nodetest" {
  version_id = "v1"
  service    = "mainApp"
  runtime    = "nodejs10"

  instance_class = "B1"

  basic_scaling {
    max_instances = 1
  }

  entrypoint {
    shell = "node test.js"
  }

  deployment {
    files {
      name       = google_storage_bucket_object.object.name
      source_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.object.name}"
    }
  }

  delete_service_on_destroy = true

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.appengine_api
  ]
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  project  = var.project_id
  name     = var.bucket_name
  location = var.region
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "object" {
  name    = "test.js"
  bucket  = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source = "test.js"
}
```

My test.js is located in the same directory as where tf is located.

**test.js**

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I see that the files have already been deployed correctly

[image]

And the error i am getting

[image]

I tried changing the url from

```
"https://storage.googleapis.com/${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.object.name}"
```

To

```
"https://storage.cloud.com/${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.object.name}"
```

Try changing the `shell = "node test.js"` to `shell = "node ./test.js"`

Also i did take a look at [GitHub Issue 4974](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/4974) but is doesnt solve my problem. I did notice that when i try to `terraform apply` the error pretty much pop up quite fast so it seem that is stuck on a very first validation error.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user that runs compute_engine.tf has "appengine.applications.create" and deploy permissions?

Also check if you set project and region in your google provider.

Comment: Yes i have them enabled and the project and region is also set

Answer (score 0):

Faced with similar issue and noticed two points:

1. For first deployment `service` should have value `default`

```
resource "google_app_engine_standard_app_version" "name" {
  version_id = "v1"
  service    = "default"
  runtime    = "nodejs18"
  # ...
}
```

2. Or terraform noob approach that worked for me is create app first time via web interface and then proceed with terraform

Hope this helps somebody